# Change table column width depending on column count

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am using Vue and I want a table to change its column width depending on the number of columns.
The detailed specification is as follows:

- First column is index column (like date or sequence number) and it always exists. Its width is 200px.
- From the second columns, each column's width is determined by equally distributing the remaining width, that is (table width - 200px) / # of columns. The width cannot be less than 150px or bigger than 300px. So if the calculated width is smaller than 150px the final width is 150px. Likewise if the width is bigger than 300px, the final width is 300px.
- If the table is not wide enough to show all columns, scrollbar must be added to see the rest of the content.

Basically I applied `width: max(150px, min(300px, calc((100% - 200px) / ${this.columnCount})))` to all `th` tag except the first one.
However, the column width becomes smaller than 150px when # of columns is big.
I am doing something wrong?

[image: Table image]

The reproduction code is available in
https://codepen.io/hitochan777/pen/mdrWxwY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be that the `100%` isn't actually referencing the table's width, but instead the TH which causes the CSS to fail.

You would instead have to fetch the width width JavaScript. You can do this by using a `ref`, and then using the implicit width instead of `100%`.

Another issue is that you want the table to be scrollable, but this isn't directly possible by applying `overflow-x: [scroll/auto]` to the table.
You instead have to wrap the table in a div and add `overflow-x: [scroll/auto]` to this element.

This wrapper is also the element you want to use when calculating the `th` width, since the table will be sized dynamically constantly depending on the `th` sizes, and therefor isn't reliable.

```js
const HelloVueApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      rowCount: 5,
      columnCount: 50,
      indexColumnStyle: {
        width: "200px",
        textAlign: "left"
      },
      tableWidth: 1980
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // Should add a debounce to the event method 
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
    // Run once on mounted to get table width
    this.onResize();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    // Remember to remove the event listener when the component is destroyed to
    // avoid memory leaks
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
  },
  methods: {
    onResize() {
      this.tableWidth = this.$refs['my-table-container'].clientWidth
    }
  },
  computed: {
    dataColumnStyle() {
      return {
        width: `max(150px, min(300px, calc((${this.tableWidth}px - ${this.indexColumnStyle.width}) / ${this.columnCount})))`,
        textAlign: "left"
      };
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(HelloVueApp).mount("#hello-vue");
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-responsive {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="hello-vue">
  <div class="table-responsive" ref="my-table-container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th :style="indexColumnStyle">date</th>
          <th v-for="c in columnCount" :style="dataColumnStyle">
            {{c}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="r in rowCount">
          <td>{{r}}</td>
          <td v-for="c in columnCount">{{c * 10}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response! It works perfectly!

"The issue appears to be that the 100% isn't actually referencing the table's width, but instead the TH which causes the CSS to fail." 

Do you happen to know if this is a browser bug or simply a specification?

Comment: Sadly I do not. I mostly just fiddled around with the codepen until I found what didn't work, which was the `100%`, so I changed it to a static `2000px` and it worked. So figured that was it, and this was the workaround I came up with.